# Vaadin keep added item

Tags: java, frameworks, vaadin

I have a 2 screens, page1 and page2
Every page has a table, table1 and table2

Is it possible to add new Item into Table1 and keep this item while going to page2 and return back?

Could you help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you should focus on a Vaadin specific solution here. What you probably want to do is design your code in such a way that each View inherits its data from a single datasource (POJO, database, etc.) and when updates to that datasource occur, each View will inherently be updated.

Comment: Try add @PreserveOnRefresh on page1 and page2 UI

Comment: You shouldn't reinitialize the view/class on every state change, only when necessary. Simply hold the already initialized instance in memory... @PreserveOnRefresh only holds the view state, so when you always create a new instance of the table this annotation is useless in this context